# Derivative of the trace of matrix product $(X^TX)^p$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let $X$ be a squared matrix,

We know that $\frac {\partial tr(X^TX)}{\partial X}$ is $2X$

But how about the case of  $\frac {\partial tr((X^TX)^2)}{\partial X}$ or even  $\frac {\partial tr((X^TX)^p)}{\partial X}$

Is there any generalization?

Note that here $(X^TX)^2 = X^TXX^TX$ and similar case applies to $(X^TX)^p$

Answer (score 7):

**Meaning of the gradient**

The first thing is to be clear what is meant by the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of a matrix function. The definition of the gradient $G(X)$ as a linear functional acting on elements $V$ of the underlying space is unambiguously defined by the limit of finite differences,
$$f'(X) \circ V = \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{s}\left[f(X+sV) - f(X) \right].$$
However, if you view the gradient not as function but rather as a vector $G(X)$, the elements of that vector depends on the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ of your space. $G(X)$ is the unique vector such that
$$f'(X) \circ V = \langle G(X),V\rangle$$
for all $V$. If you change the inner product, the entries of your gradient vector will change, but in such a way so that it's action through the inner product stays the same.

The standard inner product on matrix spaces is variously called the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product#Frobenius_product), the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) inner product, and the [Hilbert Schmidt inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) of real matrices. These refer to varying levels of generalization of the same thing:
$$\langle A,B \rangle = \sum_{ij}A_{ij}B_{ij} =\mathrm{vec}(A)^T\mathrm{vec}(B) = \mathrm{tr}(A^TB).$$

You could have other [inner products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), but they would just be the same basic inner product but with some symmetric positive definite "mass matrix" inserted into it,
$$\langle A,B \rangle_M =\mathrm{vec}(A)^TM\mathrm{vec}(B).$$

Sometimes one defines the trace in terms of the inner product (rather than as a sum of entries), in which case the situation is automatically consistent such that
$$\langle A,B \rangle_M =\mathrm{tr}_M(A^TB).$$

---

**Derivative of $\mathrm{tr}\left((X^TX)^2\right)$**

Here we choose to use the Frobenius inner product for our purposes of gradient calculation, understanding that if the inner product changes then the gradient will change by multiplication with a mass matrix.

For notation, let's call the original overall function $f$,
$$f(X):=\mathrm{tr}(X^TXX^TX).$$

Based on the linearity of the trace and the product rule for matrices, it is straightforward to evaluate the derivative of $f$ in any given direction $V$,
$$f'(X)\circ V = \mathrm{tr}(V^TXX^TX + X^TVX^TX + X^TXV^TX + X^TXX^TV).$$

However, in this form we only have the action of $f'$ as a function. To get the elements, we need to somehow gather all of the $V's$ together so that
$$f'(X) \circ V = \mathrm{tr}(V^T \mathrm{[something]}),$$

then whatever is left is the gradient in matrix form, ready to be applied. Ie,
$$G(X) = \mathrm{[something]}$$
so that
$$f'(X) \circ V = \langle G(x), V\rangle.$$

To gather all of the $V's$ into one place and transpose them as required, we're going to need to use 2 "moves". The [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) is

1. invariant under cyclic permutations,
   $\mathrm{tr}(ABC) = \mathrm{tr}(CAB) = \mathrm{tr}(BCA)$, and
2. invariant under transposes
   $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{tr}(A^T).$

Using these two moves yields,
\begin{align}
f'(X)\circ V &= \mathrm{tr}(V^TXX^TX + X^TVX^TX + X^TXV^TX + X^TXX^TV) \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(V^TXX^TX + X^TXX^TV + V^TXX^TX + X^TXX^TV) \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(V^TXX^TX + V^TXX^TX + V^TXX^TX + V^TXX^TX) \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(V^T [4XX^TX]),
\end{align}

and so
$$G(X) = 4XX^TX.$$

---

**Derivative of $\mathrm{tr}\left((X^TX)^p\right)$**

For the general case we have,
\begin{align}
f'(x) \circ V:=& \mathrm{tr}((X^TX)^p) \\
=& \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^p (X^TX)^{k-1}(V^TX)(X^TX)^{p-k} + \sum_{i=1}^p (X^TX)^{k-1}(X^TV)(X^TX)^{p-k}\right) \\
=& \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^p (V^TX)(X^TX)^{p-k}(X^TX)^{k-1} + \sum_{i=1}^p (X^TX)^{p-k}(X^TX)^{k-1}(X^TV))\right) \\
=& \mathrm{tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^p 2 V^TX(X^TX)^{p-1}\right) \\
=& 2\mathrm{tr}\left( V^T[pX(X^TX)^{p-1}]\right),
\end{align}

and so
$$G(X) = 2pX(X^TX)^{p-1}.$$

---

**Generalization to smooth functions of $X^TX$**

If you wanted to go further, you can use the result for $(X^TX)^p$ and linearity of the gradient to find the gradient for any polynomial $f(X) = q(X^TX)$ where $q(x) = \sum_k c_kx^k$, yielding
$$G(X) = \sum_k c_k k X(X^TX)^{k-1} = Xq'(X^TX).$$

Then using polynomial approximation, you can extend the result to general functions $f(X^TX)$
$$G(X) = Xf'(X^TX).$$

If you did this whole procedure with $X^p$ instead of $(X^TX)^p$, you would have come up with the theorem,
$$G(X) = f'(X^T).$$

---

Finally, if you are working with matrix calculations and derivatives, the [matrix cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) is an excellent reference. If you want to dive deep into the theory about these sort of things, the notes [Trace, Metric, and Reality: Notes on Abstract Linear Algebra](https://web.archive.org/web/20170705104037/http://users.ipfw.edu/CoffmanA/pdf/book.pdf) are great.

Comment: How about generalizing to $f(U)$ where $f$ is smooth and $U$ depends on $X$? Do we get $\frac{dU}{dX}f'(U^T)$?

Comment: I think in the case $X^TX$ you lost a factor of $2$. For example, in the last second formula, it should be $G(X)=2Xf'(X^TX)$.

Answer (score 3):

When $p=2$,
\begin{align*}
&\left[(X+\Delta X)^\top(X+\Delta X)\right]^2 - (X^\top X)^2\\
=&\left[(X+\color{red}{\Delta X})^\top(X+\color{green}{\Delta X})(X+\color{blue}{\Delta X})^\top(X+\color{orange}{\Delta X})\right] - (X^\top X)^2\\
=&\color{red}{\Delta X}^\top X(X^\top X)
+X^\top \color{green}{\Delta X} (X^\top X)
+(X^\top X)\color{blue}{\Delta X}^\top X
+(X^\top X)X^\top \color{orange}{\Delta X}+O(\|\Delta X\|^2).
\end{align*}
Therefore, using the properties $\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}\tr(AB)=\tr(BA)$ and $\tr(A^\top)=\tr(A)$, we get
$$
\tr\left\{\left[(X+\Delta X)^\top(X+\Delta X)\right]^2 - (X^\top X)^2\right\}
= 4\tr\left(\Delta X^\top X(X^\top X)\right) +O(\|\Delta X\|^2).
$$
and hence $\dfrac{\partial \tr(X^TX)}{\partial X} = 4 X(X^\top X)$. By a similar argument, one can deduce that
$\dfrac{\partial \tr\left((X^TX)^p\right)}{\partial X} = 2p X(X^\top X)^{p-1}$.